# Invokemember("onclick") return false Webbrowser

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a click button from my program, but it returns null and the debugger stops at that point.

```
HtmlElement links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Btn_Submit");
//links.InvokeMember("onclick");
//var ei = links.GetType().GetEvent("Click").GetRaiseMethod();

links.InvokeMember("onclick"); // return false

links.InvokeMember("click");  // return Null
```

HTML code of button is below:

```
 <input style="width: 77px;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Btn_Submit" class="button" tabIndex="8" onclick="if(typeof(Page_ClientValidate)=='function'){if(Page_ClientValidate(vGroup)==false){Page_BlockSubmit=false;return false;}} this.value=this.value+'...'; this.disabled=true;__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Btn_Submit','');" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Btn_Submit" value="Submit" type="submit"/><br/>
```

Comment: `onclick` is an event. Try `click` instead.

Comment: i tried click not working returns null

Comment: I have done it before, it does work. The handler in the `onclick` event is just preventing it from continuing it appears. Edit: InvokeMember("click") does return null. This is correct.

Comment: but i mydebugging point stopes at that point how can get the next page it is not going .. i want extract some data from next page

Comment: You will have to wait for the next page to load and deal with that in the DocumentCompleted event of the web browser control.

Comment: its not going . if i click manually inside wbbrowser its going..from program its not going thanks